# Search for text and navigate between the occurrences

Tags: search

I want to be able to search for some text and navigate quickly between the occurrences. What is a convenient way to search for some text, view all the occurrences, and jump quickly to the next/previous occurrence?

Comment: After @Gilles's edit, this is a good and clear question. There are various fancy packages that can do it, they should be mentioned in the answers. Emacs built-in help system won't tell user about them.

Comment: @Drew hover `your` mouse over the upvote arrow, what does it say? You opinionated stupid asshole.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Search.html#Search) is your friend!

The basic search capability is [incremental search](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Incremental-Search.html#Incremental-Search). Press `C-s` and enter the string to search (`C-r` to search backwards). [Press `C-s`/`C-r` again](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Repeat-Isearch.html#Repeat-Isearch) to go to the next/previous occurrence. Any command other than typing text, backspace and a few others exits search mode; in particular, press `RET` to continue editing where the occurrence was found or `C-g` to go back to the starting point.

Press `C-s C-s` to repeat the previous search (`C-r C-r` to repeat it backwards). After entering incrementatl search mode with `C-s` or `C-r`, press `M-p`/`M-n` to browse the search history (previous/next). Press `C-s C-w` to search for the word under the cursor (and other [similar commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Isearch-Yank.html#Isearch-Yank)).

Use `C-M-s` or `C-M-r` to [search for a regular expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Search.html#Regexp-Search) instead of a string.

If you want an overview of all the occurrences of a string (or more generally a regular expression), [`M-x occur`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Repeating-Search.html#index-mode_002c-Occur-878) is your friend. It shows a list of matching lines in a separate buffer. In the `*Occur*` buffer, press `RET` or the middle mouse button to jump to the corresponding line in the original buffer. See the manual for commands that search multiple buffers.

Comment: If you want a fancier interface [helm-swoop](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/helm-swoop) may be what you want.

Comment: @rlazo You should expand on this comment and make it an answer. Explain what Helm is and the benefits (and downsides) of helm-swoop over built-in methods.

Comment: When using isearch, `M-s o` (`isearch-occur`) will drop you in an Occur buffer showing all matches for the current search.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of just providing a link to the manual section section about searching, the real "*the manual is your friend*" answer is to tell you **how to look this up in the manual yourself**: `C-h r i searching RET` or `C-h r i search TAB ing RET`.

If someone is really at this basic a level with Emacs, then the real question is **how to look something up in the manual**, and the answer is `C-h r i`.

Emacs is self-documenting. *Start* by **asking Emacs**, not Stack Exchange. To learn to ask Emacs, start with `C-h C-h`.

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (`isearch-forward`), then type your text. Emacs will search as you type. To find the next occurrence, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> again. To go to previous occurrence, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. To stop, press <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> to leave the cursor there. Or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to return to the spot before search was started.

This command is also under the menu **Edit**.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> twice will search your last searched word.